# match the pattern of a boolean expression/ string

Tags: java

I am trying to find a way to parse the boolean expression to other format,

but first, I need to filter those pattern out.

for example, if I have a Boolean Expression:

```
((A and B) or (C and D and E)) or (A and G)
```

What I want to do is to filter the possible choice and save in a ArrayList like:

```
The Arraylist should contain:
(A and B)
(C and D and E)
(A and G)
```

This is my code:

```
String b_expression = "((A and B) or (C and D and E)) or (A and G)";
ArrayList<String> parsed_array = new ArrayList<String>();
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("/\\([a-zA-Z0-9]+\\)/");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(b_expression);
if (matcher.find()) {
    parsed_array.add(matcher.group(0));
}
```

Comment: May I suggest you to use some grammar based parser? Maybe [parboiled](https://github.com/sirthias/parboiled)

Comment: You cannot parse expressions of the type shown with regex.  You must use a real expression parser.  You are trying to use the wrong tool, i.e. a pocket-knife, when you need an industrial chain saw.